# Managing Linux user accounts + Samba + more

Tags: ldap, samba, openldap, samba4, freeipa

I have a network of about 3-6 CentOS servers, with about 5-10 users (currently, and near future). I'm looking for a solution for centralized managements of users.

My requirements from it are:

1. Linux authentication (login to servers)
2. Integration with Samba - only to expose Linux files to Windows; I don't want to use this solution to login into Windows machines
3. API to other services that need authentication, such as [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineLDAP) or Alfresco
4. Simple management

Tried OpenLDAP, but it seems too complicated for my small network. Then I've installed RedHat's IdM (=FreeIPA), which was easy to install, and very nice to administer. It's also based on LDAP, so I thought that it'd play nice with the other players.

Surprisingly, it seems that IdM/FreeIPA doesn't integrate well with Samba.
Furthermore, it appears that I was mistaken, and IdM/FreeIPA doesn't expose its LDAP database to other services - they have to be Kerberized, which complicates the business...

So, the reasonable solution appears to be back to LDAP. Am I correct?

But even with LDAP, I'm not sure what's the correct approach...

1. OpenLDAP/389 Server
2. Samba3 with LDAP backend, or Samba4 with builtin LDAP
3. https://gna.org/projects/smbldap-tools/

I'm not even sure that I'm asking the right question :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit tricky because of point 3. The LDAP in IPA is available just not anonymously, so you need to either kerberize the applications making queries OR give them a generic account to bind with. Most applications I've seen support this.

From the samba wiki: "
Note that you cannot point Samba4 to your existing OpenLDAP server and expect things to work."

Honestly depending on the specifics of requirement 3 for such a small environment I would suggest you use Active Directory (im assuming you have it already) via sssd and as the back-end to samba. This is the easiest and most maintainable solution,  assuming req 3 supports it.

Answer (score 1):

I would choose some LDAP-based solution for the flexibility and the wide-support and for the GNU/Linux world your best bet is OpenLdap. At the beginning ldap world is a bit trivial but is quite solid.

You need:

- an OpenLdap server, maybe two (in a provider-consumer fashion) if you
  need an high availability architecture, with Samba schema installed
- a Samba server configured to retrieve users and groups using Openldap as
  backend and to expose some shares
- Smbdlap tools to manage (add, edit, delete) users and groups from command line
- a web gui for simple management (add, edit, delete) of users and groups, I suggest    [fusiondirectory](https://www.fusiondirectory.org/) or in alternative a local ldap client
- configurations and packages to enable ldap support in pam and nss for GNU
  linux login.

Around there are some quite good tutorial for this setup.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to build everything from scratch, you might want to give Univention Corporate Server (UCS) a try. I work for Univention, so I know it well. It's a Debian based, enterprise level operating system that works well as domain/identity management for heterogeneous environments. There's also a free "Core Edition" that has all features you need.

Among other things, it provides:

1. authentication for clients via LDAP and/or Kerberos
2. shares via NFS and/or Samba (Samba 4 / AD also possible)
3. authentication for external services - see below for details
4. a nice web-based administration interface

As Andy pointed out, you usually don't want to expose your LDAP directory without authentication (anonymously). It's a good practice to create a special user in the LDAP directory and use this user in the third-party application to authenticate when querying the LDAP directory.

There are even articles in the Univention Wiki for Redmine and Alfresco:
[Cool Solution - Install Redmine and setup ldap authentication](http://wiki.univention.de/index.php?title=Redmine)
[Cool Solution - Alfresco](http://wiki.univention.de/index.php?title=Cool_Solution_-_Alfresco)

Further information on UCS on [Univention's website](https://www.univention.com/).

Hope, I was of help to you,
Maren